# How can I recall the Region Progress screen?

Tags: diablo-iv

When you complete certain milestones in a region, you are presented with the Region Progress screen.

[image: Region progress screen]

Is there a way to recall this screen, so that I can check my progress? Or does it only show up when I have something to claim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On PC, bring up the map, then press <kbd>W</kbd>.

[image: Right hand side of the map header bar]

If you are on an Xbox, bring up the map, then press the Y button.

For the PS5, it’s the triangle button.

Comment: Worth noting for folks not on PC, on the Map screen, over to the right hand side of the bar at the top, showed a tooltip with the button to press

Comment: Triangle is the button on ps5. Just an FYI if you'd like to  add that to your answer so it covers all platforms.